# How to publish to Sonatype using publishSigned from sbt-pgp?

Tags: sbt, nexus, sonatype

I want to publish a Scala library with sbt using sbt-pgp 0.8. I've registered groupId `org.bitbucket.sergey_kozlov` at Sonatype.

My **build.sbt**:

```
organization := "org.bitbucket.sergey_kozlov"

name := "playingcards"

version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

publishMavenStyle := true

publishTo := {
    val nexus = "https://oss.sonatype.org/"
    if (isSnapshot.value)
        Some("snapshots" at nexus + "content/repositories/snapshots")
    else
        Some("releases"  at nexus + "service/local/staging/deploy/maven2")
}

publishArtifact in Test := false

pomIncludeRepository := { _ => false }

pomExtra :=
        <url>https://bitbucket.org/sergey_kozlov/playingcards</url>
        <licenses>
            <license>
                <name>The MIT License</name>
                <url>http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php</url>
                <distribution>repo</distribution>
            </license>
        </licenses>
        <scm>
            <url>https://bitbucket.org/sergey_kozlov/playingcards.git</url>
            <connection>scm:git:ssh://git@bitbucket.org/sergey_kozlov/playingcards.git</connection>
        </scm>
        <developers>
            <developer>
                <id>skozlov</id>
                <name>Sergey Kozlov</name>
                <email>mail.sergey.kozlov@gmail.com</email>
                <roles>
                    <role>architect</role>
                    <role>developer</role>
                </roles>
            </developer>
        </developers>

libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.11"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.0" % "test"
```

There's also **~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/gpg.sbt**:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-pgp" % "0.8")
```

No other files are under `project/` directory that contribute to the build definition.

When I enter `publishSigned` in sbt console, I get the following error:

```
[error] (*:publishSigned) java.io.IOException: Access to URL https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/playingcards/playingcards_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/playingcards_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar was refused by the server: Forbidden
```

Note that the URL does not contain `organization`.

How can I publish my artifact correctly?

Comment: I don't immediately see any issues in your `build.sbt` file.  Do you have any `project/*.scala` files which may be manipulating the expected values?

Comment: What's your `project/plugins.sbt`? I suspect that `publishSigned` comes from [sbt-pgp](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-pgp) or [sbt-sonatype](https://github.com/xerial/sbt-sonatype).

Comment: @joescii I have no `*.scala` files in the `project` directory.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski My `project/plugins.sbt` contains only `logLevel := Level.Warn`, but there is `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/gpg.sbt` with such content: `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-pgp" % "0.8")`

Answer (score 2):

As you pointed out your URL is missing **organization** property this is why you get this error. Try to run `show organization` in sbt console to be sure that your organization property is correct. If it doesn't help try to specify your project explicitly in sbt and set **organization** property there.

```
lazy val core = (project in file(".")).settings(
  organization := "org.bitbucket.sergey_kozlov"
  //other properties here
)
```